# Roughly how much faster is int compared to bigint when indexing and used in ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

First I know there are many variables, but I just need something to base my decision to use int or bigint.

I have a rank field that is something like 9 to 10 digits long so I either have to decrease the precision to ensure it's never bigger than 9 digits or use bignit. My question is whether there is an information on approximations for speed of read/write, indexing and using int and bigint in ORDER BY clause?

Roughly how much faster is int compared to bigint when indexing and used in ORDER BY?

I'm asking for any benchmarks you may have done, or in your own experience.

Edit: my ranking algorithm creates rank that's a float and grows by day. by 2020 it will be 7745.9570846. I convert this number to integer by deciding how precise I want to be, for example if I decide to be precise up to 5 digits after dot, converted number would be 774595708 which fits in int even though I loose some precision. I could have more precision by using bigint, and also ensure I wont run out of space shortly after 2020, but because I am not sure what the speed tradeoffs are I'm not sure if i shoud or not

Answer (score 0):

Ints may be slightly (though unlikely in a noticable way) faster than bigints because it is less data to store, compare, etc.

The bottom line is to use the data type that fits your data, not based on some premature optimization. Build your app first, **then** optimize if there is a problem.

Comment: my ranking algorithm creates rank that's a float and grows by day. by 2020 it will be 7745.9570846. I convert this number to integer by deciding how precise I want to be, for example if I decide to be precise up to 5 digits after dot, converted number would be 774595708 which fits in int even though I loose some precision. I could have more precision by using bigint, and also ensure I wont run out of space shortly after 2020, but because I am not sure what the speed tradeoffs are I'm not sure if i shoud or not.

Comment: Pick what works best for your app, worry about speed later. It very likely will make absolutely no difference.